# Cannot execute binary file on Linux server

Tags: linux, files, binary

I'm currently trying to run Knime (a Java-based program) on a Linux server, and every time I try to execute the file (knime) it gives me a "cannot execute binary file" error. I've posted the relevant information below.

```
  uname -a
     Linux safar 2.6.32-5-amd64 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 10:07:46 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

  ls -al knime_2.6.3
     drwxrwxr-x 10 **** **** 4096 Nov 28 23:18 knime_2.6.3

  ls -al /knime_2.6.3/knime
     -rwxrwxrwx 1 **** ***** 71162 Oct 15 15:11 knime
```

For reference, the file's name is "knime" and it's within the "knime_2.6.3" folder. There are other files within that folder pertinent to Knime (which I can post information about if necessary) but the Readme simply says to execute knime. Here's the error:

```
  . knime
       -bash: .: knime: cannot execute binary file
```

I'm not really experienced with Linux, so any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: do you execute './knime' or '. knime'. Big difference between the 2.

Comment: Can you post output of `file /knime_2.6.3/knime`?

Comment: Where is the folder located? If it's in /tmp, /tmp might be mounted no-exec.

Comment: Goez is right.  The bash error indicates that you ran `. knime` instead of `./knime`.

Comment: The `.` command is equivalent to the `source` command that used to source another file with bash code.

Answer (score 1):

May be this file belong to different architecture like you are trying to run a x86 binary on a ppc system.
You can check this by using 'ldd' command for e.g.

```
ldd /knime_2.6.3/knime
```